# My apps are not visible in Show Applications screen in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, icons, 22.04, activities-overview

You can see from the screenshot that I have many apps installed (Chrome, Steam, TeamViewer, etc) but they are not being shown on my "Show Applications" screen. **In fact, it doesn't even show LibreOffice, Rhythmbox, Games or other apps.** But when I search their names, they would appear and I can run them just fine.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Here is what I already tried:

- I don't have any extensions installed.
- I tried reverting the default Gnome-Tweak settings.
- I tried resetting dconf.

Here is the output of `ls -l /usr/share/applications/`:

```
total 708
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   291 Apr 13 13:20 apport-gtk.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   125 May 19  2016 apturl.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   484 Apr  8 11:09 bluetooth-sendto.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   216 Apr 19 15:32 com.mattjakeman.ExtensionManager.desktop
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    64 Apr 15 01:12 com.teamviewer.TeamViewer.desktop -> /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/desktop/com.teamviewer.TeamViewer.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12855 May  4 19:57 defaults.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   257 Apr 12 18:30 evolution-calendar.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   303 Mar 23 13:18 gcr-prompter.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   611 Mar 23 13:18 gcr-viewer.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   227 Mar 23 06:54 geoclue-demo-agent.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   509 Jan  8 13:45 gkbd-keyboard-display.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   730 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-applications-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   667 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-background-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   815 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-bluetooth-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   819 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-camera-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   905 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-color-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   772 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-connectivity-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   758 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-control-center.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   715 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-datetime-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   778 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-default-apps-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   835 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-diagnostics-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   426 Mar 18 14:40 gnome-disk-image-mounter.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   487 Mar 18 14:40 gnome-disk-image-writer.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   888 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-display-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   999 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-info-overview-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   374 Mar 29 00:35 gnome-initial-setup.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   877 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-keyboard-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   494 Apr  9 15:41 gnome-language-selector.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   864 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-location-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   849 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-lock-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   842 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-microphone-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 16033 Mar 22 05:45 gnome-mimeapps.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   852 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-mouse-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   707 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-multitasking-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   814 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-network-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   894 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-notifications-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1000 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-online-accounts-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   929 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-power-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   816 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-printers-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   810 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-region-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   843 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-removable-media-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   834 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-search-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   475 Apr  7 12:07 gnome-session-properties.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   749 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-sharing-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   850 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-sound-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   789 Mar 21 07:13 gnome-system-monitor.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   762 Mar 21 07:13 gnome-system-monitor-kde.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   784 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-thunderbolt-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   622 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-ubuntu-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1023 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-universal-access-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   844 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-usage-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   919 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-user-accounts-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   815 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-wacom-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   806 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-wifi-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   723 Apr 20 12:02 gnome-wwan-panel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  8515 Apr 29 18:25 google-chrome.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   423 Mar 23 06:52 hplj1020.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2546 Mar 23 06:58 htop.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   204 Feb  1 18:04 ibus-setup-table.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   258 Jan 21 13:18 im-config.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   217 Feb  6 04:48 info.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   146 Apr 21 01:50 io.snapcraft.SessionAgent.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 22733 Apr 12 07:49 libreoffice-calc.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 19674 Apr 12 07:49 libreoffice-draw.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 22756 Apr 12 07:49 libreoffice-impress.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18495 Apr 12 07:49 libreoffice-math.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21601 Apr 12 07:49 libreoffice-startcenter.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21566 Apr 12 07:49 libreoffice-writer.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4733 Apr 12 07:49 libreoffice-xsltfilter.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 23861 May  4 21:00 mimeinfo.cache
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   353 Mar 25 06:55 nautilus-autorun-software.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   350 Mar  7 07:56 nm-applet.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   447 Mar  7 07:56 nm-connection-editor.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   200 Feb 14 07:48 nvidia-settings.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   159 Apr 10 05:16 org.freedesktop.IBus.Panel.Emojier.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   181 Apr 10 05:16 org.freedesktop.IBus.Panel.Extension.Gtk3.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   363 Apr 10 05:16 org.freedesktop.IBus.Setup.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   623 Feb 14 10:57 org.gnome.baobab.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   709 Mar 21 07:38 org.gnome.Calculator.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   558 Feb 14 13:34 org.gnome.Calendar.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   602 Mar 19 10:33 org.gnome.Characters.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   581 Mar 23 02:46 org.gnome.Cheese.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   634 Feb 14 11:30 org.gnome.DejaDup.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   699 Mar 18 14:40 org.gnome.DiskUtility.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1136 Mar 21 06:05 org.gnome.eog.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1387 Apr 13 09:43 org.gnome.Evince.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   401 Apr 13 09:43 org.gnome.Evince-previewer.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   470 Mar 19 18:45 org.gnome.Evolution-alarm-notify.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2153 Mar 21 05:57 org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   843 Feb 14 09:08 org.gnome.font-viewer.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   749 Mar  2 04:34 org.gnome.gedit.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   565 Mar 28 13:31 org.gnome.Logs.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   529 Mar 21 11:16 org.gnome.Mahjongg.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   704 Feb 18 06:33 org.gnome.Mines.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1240 Mar 25 06:55 org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   741 Mar 23 06:55 org.gnome.PowerStats.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   597 Feb 16 12:06 org.gnome.seahorse.Application.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   388 Apr 12 18:30 org.gnome.Shell.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   357 Apr 12 18:30 org.gnome.Shell.Extensions.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   326 Apr 12 18:30 org.gnome.Shell.PortalHelper.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   659 Mar 17 13:54 org.gnome.Sudoku.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   562 Mar 28 05:51 org.gnome.Terminal.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   496 Mar 24 03:03 org.gnome.Todo.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2656 Mar 21 06:51 org.gnome.Totem.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   588 Apr 20 12:29 org.gnome.tweaks.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  6034 Mar 25 12:03 org.remmina.Remmina.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   705 Mar 25 12:03 org.remmina.Remmina-file.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   224 Apr  2 02:04 python3.10.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   299 Mar 10 07:34 remmina-gnome.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1236 Feb 17 10:39 rhythmbox.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   632 Feb 17 10:39 rhythmbox-device.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   529 Jan 31 17:56 rygel.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   774 Apr 19 23:22 shotwell.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1128 Apr 19 23:22 shotwell-viewer.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   528 Mar 19 10:36 simple-scan.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   218 Apr 21 01:50 snap-handle-link.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   362 Apr  1 11:48 software-properties-drivers.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   580 Apr  1 11:48 software-properties-gtk.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   352 Apr  1 11:48 software-properties-livepatch.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   296 Mar 31 05:08 sol.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7473 Dec  1 08:41 steam.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   518 Feb 21 06:01 system-config-printer.desktop
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    50 Apr 15 01:12 teamviewer8.desktop -> /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/desktop/teamviewer8.desktop
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    52 Apr 15 01:12 teamviewerapi.desktop -> /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/desktop/teamviewerapi.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   817 Mar 25 02:52 transmission-gtk.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   302 Apr 11 00:56 update-manager.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   288 Mar  4 04:59 usb-creator-gtk.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5090 Apr 18 12:26 vim.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   208 May  4 20:13 vmware-netcfg.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   279 May  4 20:13 vmware-player.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   323 May  4 20:13 vmware-workstation.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   247 Apr  5 11:24 xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   620 Mar 25 02:53 xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   614 Mar 28 05:21 yelp.desktop
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question adding the output of `ls -l  /usr/share/applications/`? Apps appear in the App Grid because there is a related .desktop in that folder. It may be interesting to check if the .desktop files are present or not.

Comment: @LorenzKeel Done

Comment: Does `xdg-desktop-menu forceupdate` or `update-desktop-database` and a restart fix it?

Comment: @PabloBianchi no change

Comment: Have you tried running `update-desktop-database -v` and checked for errors?

Comment: I have the same exact issue going on, and have tried all the "solutions" I can find to no avail. Is there a bug open for this or any other suggestions available?? I'm going batty trying to figure this out.

Answer (score -2):

I came across the same issue on a fresh installation today.
I'm certain the problem is caused by some snap packages, most likely snap store and gnome desktop.

My solution was to remove snap completely. After that all my application launchers returned.

Since Ubuntu 22.04 is still quite new, we may have to wait before they fix this bug.

Comment: I tried removing all snaps and the snap daemon. It didn't fix it.